# Can't change the style using a button in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, frontend

I'm trying to make a hamburger menu, which will hide or show the links to other parts in the site, but when I try to change the visibility it doesn't work. Can someone explain, please?

```
export default function Mainpage(){
import barrinha from './menu.svg'

var visivel = {
  visibility: "hidden"
}

var clicks = false;

function arrastar_pro_lado(){ 
  clicks = !clicks
  if(clicks == false){
     visivel = {visibility: "hidden"}
  }else{
    visivel = {visibility: "visible"}
  }
}
return(
        <div>
          <button id='barrinha' onClick={arrastar_pro_lado()}><img src={barrinha}/></button>
            <div id='menu' style={visivel}>
                <a >ver perfil</a>
                <a >criar eventos</a>
                <a >consultar eventos</a>
                <a >historico de eventos</a>
                <a >Sair</a>
            </div>
);}
```

Comment: Note you are executing the function immediatly instead of setting it as a callback/event listener, `onClick={arrastar_pro_lado()}`, should be like `onClick={arrastar_pro_lado}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a state variable. You can use the React hook useState like this.

Inside your click handler, call setVisible with a state updater function that will toggle the state value.

It is important that you use the updater function form of setState, because the next state depends on the previous state.

It is tempting to simply write `setState(!state)`, however this can lead to inconsistent results.

Instead write `setState(prevState => !prevState)`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import barrinha from './menu.svg';

export default function Mainpage() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  function arrastar_pro_lado() {
    setVisible((visible) => !visible);
  }

  const visivel = {
    visibility: visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden',
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button id="barrinha" onClick={arrastar_pro_lado}>
        <img src={barrinha} />
      </button>
      <div id="menu" style={visivel}>
        <a>ver perfil</a>
        <a>criar eventos</a>
        <a>consultar eventos</a>
        <a>historico de eventos</a>
        <a>Sair</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I have a question . When I should use State and why. Why can't you just store the value false in a variable?

Comment: @babukinha Every time React calls your function component, the variable will be destroyed and re-created. Instead use state. I suggest reading the documentation on state. https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: @babukinha I have one more link for you to read: useState hook. https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 0):

On click, you need to change *state* so as to trigger a re-render:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button id='barrinha' onClick={() => setVisible(!visible)}>
        <img src='https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XxxUtSmCY-g/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAARG0/at7iXI-hi94/photo.jpg?sz=32' />
      </button>
      <div id='menu' style={{ visibility: visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}>
          <a >ver perfil</a>
          <a >criar eventos</a>
          <a >consultar eventos</a>
          <a >historico de eventos</a>
          <a >Sair</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import barrinha from './menu.svg';

export default function Mainpage () {
  // local state
  const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false);

  function arrastar_pro_lado () {
    // when user click on button, change the previous status of Menu
    setIsMenuVisible(!isMenuVisible);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button id='barrinha' onClick={arrastar_pro_lado}>
        <img src={barrinha} />
      </button>
      <div id='menu' style={{ visibility: isMenuVisible ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}>
        <a>ver perfil</a>
        <a>criar eventos</a>
        <a>consultar eventos</a>
        <a>historico de eventos</a>
        <a>Sair</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```